# Some variant of Law of Large Numbers for any continuous function?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers, uniform-integrability

Let $\{X_i\}$ be iid random variables on $\mathbb R$ $X_i\sim X$,  let $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function s.t. expectations   $\mathrm EX$ and $\mathrm Ef(X)$ are finite.
Does it follow that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm Ef\left(\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}n\right)=f(\mathrm EX)?
$$

If not, what are the condition for this to hold? If random variable $X$ is bounded a.s. it seems to follow from [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $\overline X_n = (X_1+\dots+X_n)/n$. By LLN, $f(\overline X_n) \to f(\mathrm E X)$, so your question is essentially about uniform integrability of $f(\overline X_n)$. The finiteness of $\mathrm E f(X)$ is certainly not enough for that; in fact, $\mathrm E f(\overline X_n)$ may even be infinite. As an example, you can take an integer-valued and unbounded $X$ (e.g. Poisson) and let $f$ be zero at all integers, but behave very wildly in between them: on $[n,n+1]$, $f$ very rapidly grows to $e^{e^n}$ as we move from the endpoints. With a little more ingenuity, you can make $f(\overline X_n)$ to be integrable, but $\mathrm E f(\overline X_n)$ to converge (or diverge) wherever you like.

Speaking of sufficient conditions, one which comes to my mind is that $|f| \le g$, $g$ is convex, and $g(X)$ is integrable. Then you can derive the uniform integrability from Jensen's inequality:
$$
g(\overline X_n) = g(\mathrm E [X_1 \mid X_1 + \dots + X_n]) \le \mathrm E[g(X_1)\mid X_1+\dots +X_n], 
$$
and the rhs is well known to be uniformly integrable.

Comment: It was very helpful, thanks. Could you please give some reference for the rhs to be uniformly integrable?

Comment: @Andrew e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731917/uniform-integrability-of-all-conditional-expectations-of-a-fixed-l1-function)

Comment: @Andrew by the way, for bounded $X$ the Hoeffding inequality is an overkill: the means obviously have the same bound, so $f(\overline X_n)$ are bounded, and we can appeal to the bounded convergence.