# If for any $a$, $g(a, b) \rightarrow 0$ as $b \rightarrow \infty$, then does $\sup_a g(a, b) \rightarrow 0$ when $b \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, uniform-integrability

Here, $f:A \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is some real-valued function, $A$ is some nonempty set.

motivation: a set of random variables $\{X_\alpha\}$ is uniformaly integrable if $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{\alpha}E[|X_\alpha| 1_{|X_\alpha| > K}] = 0$, now if I know for any $\alpha$, $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty}E[|X_\alpha| 1_{|X_\alpha| > K}] = 0$, can I conclude that the set of random variables is uniformly integrable?

Comment: No. Your assumption only tells you that each $X_{\alpha}$ is integrable, not that the whole family is  uniformly integrable.

Comment: My intuition also tells me this is not correct. Some proofs about uniform integrability are so short that they confused me, like this [one](https://planetmath.org/conditionalexpectationsareuniformlyintegrable) and this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731917/uniform-integrability-of-all-conditional-expectations-of-a-fixed-l1-function), which made me think my claim is used in the proofs......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g(a,b)=\frac ab$, defined on $\mathbb R_+^2$. Then, for any $a\in\mathbb R_+$, it is easy to see that $$\lim_{b\to\infty}g(a,b)=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{a}{b}=a\cdot \lim_{b\to\infty}\frac1b = 0$$

however, for every $b\in\mathbb R_+$, we also have $$\sup_a g(a,b)=\sup_a \frac ab = \frac 1b\cdot \sup_a (a) = \infty$$ which means that the limit

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\sup_a g(a,b)$$ does not exist.

Comment: thank you, nice example